Static assert for a string comparison in a const struct member
The best way to describe what I'm asking is with the example.
Say, I have a struct that defines an element:
struct ELEMENT
{
    const char* pNameA;
    int val;
};

There's a specific order of these ELEMENTs in some particular array:
enum ELEMENT_ORDER
{
    EO_First,
    EO_Second,
    //... and so on

    EO_Count
};

The array of ELEMENTs is defined as const static for efficiency (there's no actual code that fills it in at runtime):
static const ELEMENT elements[] =
{
    {"First element name",},
    {"Second element name",},
    // ... The real array is larger than just 2 elements
};

static_assert(_countof(elements) == EO_Count, "Struct is not fully filled in");

Then I can use these ELEMENTs, as such:
ProcessElement(elements[EO_Second]);

This works, except that I want to ensure that ELEMENTs in my elements array are declared in the correct order to match ELEMENT_ORDER, so I was looking to do static_assert by their names.
I was following this example, where I first declare:
#include <string_view>
constexpr bool strings_equal(char const * a, char const * b) 
{
    return std::string_view(a)==b;
}

and then check it as such during compile time:
static_assert(strings_equal(elements[EO_First].pNameA, "First element name"), "string order mismatch");
static_assert(strings_equal(elements[EO_Second].pNameA, "Second element name"), "string order mismatch");

Again, the idea is to do these checks during compile-time.
But unfortunately, VS 2022 C++ compiler is giving me this error for my static_assert(strings_equal)s:
error C2131: expression did not evaluate to a constant

Any idea if this is possible to do with a modern C++?
PS. My project is currently set up to use C++17. But I can change it to a later standard.

-> static constexpr ELEMENT elements[]. const might act as constexpr only for integral types.

Hi, @Jarod42 ,  Please consider posting comment as answer. In addition, remove one ), "First element name")), 

The primary difference between const and constexpr variables is that the initialization of a const variable can be deferred until run time. A constexpr variable must be initialized at compile time.

@MinxinYu-MSFT That's not correct. The decision for whether a static storage duration variable must have constant initialization is independent of constexpr and is instead purely decided by whether or not the full-expression of the initialization is a constant expression. The only effect of constexpr here is to make the variable usable in constant expressions. It must have constant initialization (i.e. initialization at compile-time) regardless.
